# Is there an API to create a Feed Group in getstream-io?

Tags: getstream-io

I want to have a rake task to set up the GetStream environment with all 6 feed groups we have in our platform, but can't find a documented API for managing feed groups.

Is there an API somewhere that I missed?  Is there an undocumented one I could use in the meantime?

Answer (score 2):

We don't have an API to create feed groups, you need to create those manually within your app on the [dashboard](https://getstream.io/dashboard). It's a one-time setup step and not something you need to do over and over.

Are you trying to set up a test environment where you rebuild your feeds, or something of that nature? We do allow you to truncate all items from your feeds, but it's also a manual step because we prompt for confirmation as it's an irreversible step.

Comment: We're an open source project, so one of the frequent tasks is getting people onboarded with a development environment.  It's much easier to tell people "Grab a Stream account, paste your keys in and run `rake stream:setup`" than "go to Stream, create an app, and add the following list of feed groups from the dashboard there"

Comment: I'll mention it to the team to see if they're open to adding it as a roadmap item, but as of today there are no plans to add such an endpoint.

Comment: can you add a link to your project?

Comment: @iandouglas Is this functionality exposed by the public API now? Currently designing an app that would require creating feed groups on-demand.

Comment: I've been away from the company for a while, but I don't see anything in their documentation for this yet. Best to reach out to their support team.